# Import statement does not list my custom C++ exposed class

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am working on some demo project for my customer using Qt that uses mysql database with QML. Now, I've created basic gui using QML, created basic database class, here is project file:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick sql

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    uesqldatabase.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)

HEADERS += \
    uesqldatabase.h
```

Here is exposed class header file:

```
#ifndef UESQLDATABASE_H
#define UESQLDATABASE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>

class UeSqlDatabase : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(bool isConnected READ isConnected NOTIFY ueConnectedChanged)

private:
    bool m_ueConneted;

    inline void setConnected(const bool& ueConnected)
        { this->m_ueConneted=ueConnected; }

public:
    explicit UeSqlDatabase(QObject *parent = 0);

    inline const bool& isConnected() const
        { return this->m_ueConneted; }

    ~UeSqlDatabase();

signals:
    void ueConnectedChanged();

public slots:
    void ueConnectToDatabase (const QString& ueStrHost, const QString& ueStrDatabase,
                              const QString& ueStrUsername, const QString& ueStrPassword);
};

#endif // UESQLDATABASE_H
```

Here is exposed class implementation:

```
#include "uesqldatabase.h"

UeSqlDatabase::UeSqlDatabase(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    this->setConnected(false);
}   // constructor

UeSqlDatabase::~UeSqlDatabase()
{
}   // destructor

void UeSqlDatabase::ueConnectToDatabase (const QString& ueStrHost, const QString& ueStrDatabase,
                                         const QString& ueStrUsername, const QString& ueStrPassword)
{
    QSqlDatabase db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL",
                                              "testDb");

    db.setHostName(ueStrHost);
    db.setDatabaseName(ueStrDatabase);
    db.setUserName(ueStrUsername);
    db.setPassword(ueStrPassword);

    if(db.open())
    {
        this->setConnected(true);
    }
}   // ueConnectToDatabase
```

And here is `main.cpp` code:

```
#include <QtQml>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "uesqldatabase.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    qmlRegisterType<UeSqlDatabase>("si.mikroelektronika",
                                   1,
                                   0,
                                   "UeSqlDatabase");

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

The application runs without problems, but when I try to import exposed class (`UeSqlDatabase`) in `main.qml`, the QtCreator cannot find my class. What am I doing wrong/missing?

Comment: What's your import statement? Try `import si.mikroelektronika 1.0`

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld that was it! I issued wrong `import` statement! Can you promote comment to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the module, not the class. The import corresponding with your `qmlRegisterType` call would be

```
import si.mikroelektronika 1.0
```